# 'Class' as PHP Class name

Tags: php, oop, symfony, laravel

I want to create a class in my Laravel 5 project called 'Class'. When I create this class just like any other I get an error (which is pretty logic because we also have the class operator in PHP).

For those interested in the pretty self-explanatory error exception I get:
`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Ok I get why this error pops up, but I'm wondering if there is a way to call a class 'Class' because in my project I'm working with different School Classes.

Comment: @lukasgeiter That'd be pretty stupid...  :(

Comment: Just call it `SchoolClass`

Comment: Meh don't like that too much...

Comment: @Daniel Even if it was technicaly possible if would make your code harder to read and maintain. So it's a no-no. Do what lukasgeiter suggested.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137715/a-class-named-class .Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

No  one way to define class with name from list of reserved words.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: @DanielGelling PHP sucks because it has reserved words? In that case every language sucks.

Comment: @DanielGelling and just how would that work? You just need to think a bit harder :)

Comment: @DanielGelling Subject, Topic, Vocation, Room, Material, Matter, Curriculum...